# grep or awk script parsing library for C++ (windows)

Tags: c++, windows, parsing, awk, grep

I am interested in writing a personal program for a kind of thought organizer/pseudo database for things I am doing, something I can tailor to my needs while learning more about C++. I mainly operate on a windows system, but have been doing work in a linux environment and have been learning to use grep and awk and some really handy utilities. I would like to use grep and awk style commands, and I wanted to know where I could find libraries for parsing them, if they exist?

Comment: Boost didn't have it ?

Comment: I'm still a novice, didn't even realize boost probably has at least part of what I'm looking for. I found grep, but not so sure about awk. Searching about awk in Boost was yielding a POSIX-Extended Regular Expression Syntax. Not exactly sure what that is.

Comment: google POSIX Extended Regular Expression Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them under Cygwin or Mingw on Windows , if you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

I made a limited "grep library" usable under MinGW64 and a DLL for use with Visual Studio. It only counts matches.

Get it [here](https://ln.sync.com/dl/7c72e5840/gfnya6ma-ajndffi6-auq2w3nb-dkf9vvgj).

It even supports threads. An example is included.

`grep` is super-non-reentrant. It carries a ton of state, so this is a super ugly hack. It's only merit is that it **works**. Tested. 12 threads, millions of lines, no problem.

I had to get `grep` power. Nothing comes close in terms of speed !

I replaced main() with two entry points that accept either an array of strings or a pattern file (the latter is not tested at all ! Use `grep_keys()`).

Making grep a clean library, or porting it to WinAPI is an almost complete rewrite, from what I saw.

Again, this is a hack, so no comments please. Instead, be productive and clean it up, or ask grep developers to make it a lib. Those guys are on to something. `grep` is in a league of its own.